# Send POST requests with values from a list

Tags: python, post, http-post, python-requests

I am trying to send http POST requests to a website, with the data for the "value" key being pulled from lines of a .txt list.

I have tried to use arrays, but the website doesn't accept multiple values. Instead, I need to send a new request for each value from the file, but I can't figure out how to do this.

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Referer': 'http://127.0.0.1:2372/overrides?sid=69',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.3.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0.1 Safari/604.3.5',
    'Origin': 'http://127.0.0.1:2372',
    'DNT': '1',
}

data = [
  ('sid', '69'),
  ('aid', 'addEntry'),
  ('type', '0'),
  ('value', 'test3'),
]

requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:2372/k9ajax', headers=headers, data=data)
```

I apologize if this is a stupid question, and I will remove the post if this is the wrong forum to ask.

Answer (score 0):

please learn see  help

```
>>> import requests
>>> print(help(requests.post))
### some text
:param data: (optional) Dictionary (will be form-encoded), bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the :class:`Request`.
### some text
```

data should is a dict

```
data = {
'sid': '7882493',
'aid':'addEntry',
'type': '0',
'value':'test3'}
```